# Pseudo class not applying to entire form

Tags: css, forms, focus

The below CCS override has been applied to my [site](https://www.collierhomes.com.au) but is not working on the final field of the contact form (which is a question and answer box)? Can someone please assist?

Thank you in advance.

```
.textarea:focus, input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #be9e7d !important;
}
```

Comment: i think it's because you have `.form-control:focus` in your css

Comment: Thank you, now fixed. What an awesome community this is! :)